# Webservices in BlackBerry

Tags: java, web-services, blackberry, java-me

I am trying to make an application that will connect to a web service and call functions from it. I have worked on HTTP connections that will hit the server. This one will send me data. But can I hit a web service and call functions from it on Blackberry? I don't have such information yet haven't tried it.

So the question is, how to connect to a web service and call functions from it?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to directly call functions on the server from the BB, so you'll have to define calls on the server where your app would provide the information needed for your server side script to perform the necessary operations.

As a simple example, maybe your app sends something to the server to a login URL with a payload that has the username and password. The server would then take over and perform all of the necessary validation and come back with a simple "authenticated" or "denied" response. Your app didn't actually do anything other than provide the information that would be needed for the server to do its magic.